# Apache vhost for subdomain redirects to root

Tags: virtualhost

So. I have three sites, which are located at the same host:

- example.com
- example2.com
- sub.example.com

Files on servers are located like this:

```
/var/www/example.com
/var/www/example2.com
/var/www/example.com/sub
```

I have three vhosts:

- 000-default.conf

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com 
    ServerAlias www.example.com   
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost   
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com 
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- example2.conf

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example2.com 
    ServerAlias www.example2.com  
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost   
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example2.com    
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- sub.conf

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.example.com 
    ServerAlias www.sub.example.com   
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost   
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/sub 
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

So, example.com and example2.com work without problem. But sub.example.com redirects all requests to /var/www and shows folders listings. Is there some specific configuration for subdomain vhosts?

---

Update: 
I tried one more time to move sub to /var/www and rewrite sub vhost. After restart in some magic way it works. Bu i still can't understand why, Although, problem is solved

Comment: If there is no specific reason to have `sub.example.com` docroot under `example.com` domain, I would move it to completely separate place from `example.com`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "redirects all requests to". Can you give a more concrete example what this redirect is?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen - do you mean physical location? I tried to move folder sub to /var/www - but it works in the same way. If i visit sub.example.com, apache redirects me to /var/www folder listing. For example, sub.example.com/index.html gives me 404 (on apache log i have error - /var/www/index.html not found). That is what i mean

Comment: Configure separate logs for each site (which I find a good ideea to do whenever there are multiple sites on one server). Then see which site is chosen to serve sub.example.com so you know where to start debugging

Comment: @Dan i have separate logging. When i'm trying to get access to sub.example.com/index.php - error appears in general log (/var/www/index.php not found) and error_sub.log is still empty

Comment: So apache does not select the correct vhost but goes to default. Check if sub vhost is active. Check if dns entry for sub is correct.

Comment: @Dan sub vhost is active and DNS configured correctly. I checked this already

Answer (score 0):

Update: I tried one more time to move sub to /var/www and rewrite sub vhost. After restart in some magic (with /var/www/sub as RootDirectory) way it works. But i still can't understand why, Although, problem is solved